# How to check if a track is already published?

Tags: javascript, twilio-video

```js
for (const localTrack of localTracks) {
  if (localTrack.kind === 'video') {
    localParticipant.publishTrack(localTrack, {
      priority: 'low',
    });
  } else {
    localParticipant.publishTrack(localTrack, {
      priority: 'standard',
    });
  }
}
```

I am currently getting an error:

> TwilioError: Track name is duplicated

This is because this method is called multiple times (each time a new permission is approved) with the list of all approved tracks.

How do I check if a particular track has been already published?

One would expect that we can inspect the `localParticipant` object, e.g.

```
console.log(
  '>>>',
  localParticipant.tracks.size,
  localParticipant.audioTracks.size,
  localParticipant.videoTracks.size
);
```

but the above produces `>>> 0 0 0` and then is followed by "Track name is duplicated" error. So there is some race-condition error.

Comment: [PublishedTrack?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/publishedtrack)

Comment: The problem appears to be because [`publishTrack`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0/docs/LocalParticipant.html#publishTrack__anchor) returns a problem. That explains it. The solution is therefore to implement some sort of mutually exclusive lock. Will share a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a race condition, and to understand how we got there, we need the full code example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!localParticipant) {
    return;
  }

  for (const localTrack of localTracks) {
    if (localTrack.kind === 'video') {
      localParticipant.publishTrack(localTrack, {
        priority: 'low',
      });
    } else {
      localParticipant.publishTrack(localTrack, {
        priority: 'standard',
      });
    }
  }

  return () => {
    localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach((publication) => {
      publication.unpublish();
    });

    localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((publication) => {
      publication.unpublish();
    });
  };
}, [localParticipant, localTracks]);
```

What is happening here is that every time `localParticipant` or `localTracks` change, we do two things:

1. We clean-up by unsetting any existing audio/ video tracks
2. We bind new tracks

Somehow the clean up logic causes the `localParticipant.publishTrack` method to go into an error state ("Track name is duplicated") `publishTrack` is invoked just after `unpublish`.

The fix is to simply move `unpublish` logic into a separate hook that does not depend on `localTracks`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!localParticipant) {
    return;
  }

  return () => {
    localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach((publication) => {
      publication.unpublish();
    });

    localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((publication) => {
      publication.unpublish();
    });
  };
}, [localParticipant]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!localParticipant) {
    return;
  }

  for (const localTrack of localTracks) {
    if (localTrack.kind === 'video') {
      localParticipant.publishTrack(localTrack, {
        priority: 'low',
      });
    } else {
      localParticipant.publishTrack(localTrack, {
        priority: 'standard',
      });
    }
  }
}, [localParticipant, localTracks]);
```

Note that you need to do this in addition for handling events. The unmount clean-up strategy is used here primarily to enable react hot reloading.